# Switch between two windows / tabs in a browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am able to move (window.open) from page "A" on parent window to page "B" on child window but not the other way round. I tried window.opener.alert but it only works on chrome and opera. 
I cannot use history.go(-1) history.go(1) because there is a login page between page A and B

I need it to work on especially Safari. How can i achieve this. Is there another way to do this? A solution without the alert will even be better. Thanks for the help

page "A"

```
var pop;
function openPageB() 
{
    if (typeof (pop) == 'undefined' || pop.closed)
    {
        pop = window.open('pageb.php?', 'bWindow');
    }
    else
    {
        pop.focus();
    }
}
```

Page "B"

```
function openPageA()
{

    //window.opener.focus();
    window.opener.alert('Child window');

}
```

Answer (score 1):

After days and hours of trying to solve this with little success, i finally found a way around it which works for me. I thought of putting it here for other who may also be searching for solution.

On Page "B", since window.opener.alert('---') does not open/focus the parent tab on all browsers, i replaced that line with self.close() which will close child  tab i.e Page "B" and focus the Parent tab.

Clicking on the Button that call the function openPageB() on the parent tab will always open the child tab again. This is the edited code for returning to the parent tab. Enjoy using it.

```
function openPageA()
{

    self.close() //this line did it

}
```